# No logro ocultar modal una vez abierta js bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal

que tal llevo horas intentando descubrir porque no se cierra la ventana modal cuando se lo digo a ver si alguien me muestra la luz!

Aqui dejo el codigo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnProcesando").hide();

    $('#btnGuardarDatos').on('click',function(){


        $("#ModalProcesando").modal("show");//<--- agregar beforesend 
        $("#btnProcesando").show();
        $("#btnGuardarDatos").hide();

        var formulario = $("#formulario-alta");
        //Metodo 2 ****
        var url_destino = 'detalle_empleado.php?id_empleado=';
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'addData.php',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formulario.serialize(), 

            success:function(data){             
                if(data["estado"] === 'ok'){

                    //Ocultamos Modal Procesando 
                    $("#ModalProcesando").modal("hide");

                    $("#btnProcesando").hide();
                    //Abrimos modal, quito permisos uso del teclado para que solo puedan apretar boton de ACEPTAR (**)
                    $("#ModalOK").modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false},"show");
                    //Mostramos Mensaje en DIV en la modal ModalOK
                    $('#MensajeOK').html(data.mensaje_success);
                    //Ocultamos el Botón para evitar que se vuelva a enviar el formulario
                    $("#btnGuardarDatos").hide();
                    //Tambien reseteo el formulario
                    $('#formulario-alta')[0].reset();                    

                    $('#btnConfirmacionOK').on('click',function(){
                   //Metodo 1
                   //window.location =  ('detalle_empleado.php?id_empleado='+data.idusuario);
                   //Metodo 2 ****
                   window.location = (url_destino+data.idusuario);
                    });
                }
                if(data["estado"] === 'error'){

                    //Ocultamos Modal Procesando
                    $("#ModalProcesando").modal("hide");
                    $("#btnProcesando").hide();
                    $("#btnGuardarDatos").show();

                    //alert ('GRABADO CORRECTAMENTE'); //Depuracion

                    // No deshabilitamos ni modificamos nada
                    $("#ModalError").modal("show");
                    $('#mensajeError').html(data.mensaje_error);
                }                
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Las modales las muestra perfectamente cuando las llamo pero no me deja ocultar esta en concreto la del id:  $("#ModalProcesando").modal("hide"); Mostrarla cuando le doy al click enviar funciona pero cuando recibo respuesta OK o ERROR no se oculta.

Comment: Que te da el `console.log(data)`?

Comment: tambien he realizado la prueba de lanzar el comando por consola y ejecuto: $("#ModalProcesando").modal("hide"); la modal desaparece. De la unica forma vamos... algo me estoy olvidando de poner

Comment: console no lanza ningun error

Comment: Me refiero a si lo que recibes en data lo estas procesando bien para entrar a los `if`

Comment: siii el resto de funciones va perfectamente me muestra las modales, de error si hay error de aceptar e ir a ficha si esta ok incluso el boton de enviar lo reemplaza por el spinner de procesando. lo unico que no esta haciendo es ocultar la modal procesando cuando finaliza POST a finalizar la operacion ya puse en complete y tampoco funciona

Comment: Nada sigo sin poder hacer que se esconda la modal al decirle que lo haga... lo gracioso es que los div o elementos button si los oculta y los muestra cuando le digo

Comment: Nadie puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una función que restaure la vista sin modal

```
<script>
function removeModal (target) {
    $(target).removeClass('in');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('body').css('padding-right', '');
    $(target).hide();
}

// Sustituye
$("#ModalProcesando").modal("hide");
// por
removeModal('#ModalProcesando');
```

Espero te funcione

Comment: Voy a probar muchas gracias!!!!